# Universal CSS template for global styles

Tags: html, css

I 'm trying to create a universal CSS template for global styles. I can not find unambiguous recommendations. After inspecting various sites, I have compiled the following template . I ask your advice . Thank you!

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    // background-color: x;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    color: x;
    background-color: x;
    font-family: x;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: x;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: x;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 320px;
    padding: x;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to get from such *universal CSS template*? Have you seen [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or similar ones?

Comment: Yes, I use normalize.css. Do you think that it contains everything you need to start ? Can I ask you what styles for html and body you normally use in your projects ?

Comment: It's [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) typically. Not only it *normalizes* the CSS but also provides you with tons of predefined nicely looking [styles](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) and [components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/).

Comment: I try to avoid using css frameworks , but thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

> I can not find unambiguous recommendations. After inspecting various sites, I have compiled the following template

The canonical [example domain](http://www.example.com/) exists for such a purpose. Here is its style declaration:

```
body {
    background-color: #f0f0f2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

}
div {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 5em auto;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #38488f;
    text-decoration: none;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    body {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    div {
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 0;
        padding: 1em;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: And I'm pretty sure that's not the purpose of `example.org`, `example.com` and friends - any stylesheet served by their HTTP server is purely incidental rather than pedagogic.